# Increase height of UIView above UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I added a UIView above a UITableView via the storyboard.  I was wondering if there is a good way to increase the height of the UIView programmatically and push down the table cells.  The UITableView is a static table.

I'm using this code:

```
CGRect newFrame = myUIView.frame;
newFrame.size.height = 300;
myUIView.frame = newFrame;
```

With this code, the UIView height is increasing, but it is overlapping the table cells below it.  Is there any way to "push" the tableview lower?

thanks!

Comment: Consider using [Auto Layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using storyboard, the easiest and cleanest way is to just change the size of the `UITableView` and move it down to make room for the `UIView`. You then can move/change the `UIView` to whatever size you want.

Non-storyboard solution. Change the frame of the UITableView also.

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,height,width);
```

Comment: I was hoping to do this programmatically because I have to adjust the heights based on certain dynamic factors. I tried to adjust the frame of the table but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: When trying to adjust the frame what happened?

Comment: The UIView increases but the table does not shift down...even w/ setting the new frame.  Perhaps there is something I am doing wrong.

Comment: It's difficult to pinpoint if you did something wrong in the storyboard. Possibly, one thing I would double check is to make sure that myUIView is a subview your View not a subview of the UITableView.

Comment: If you make it a subview of the vc instead of the tableview you cant make a header like we want

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autolayout this is pretty simple.
Pin the height of the UIView.  This will create an NSLayoutConstraint for the height.   Then create a property for this and update in your code as required.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *uiview1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *uiViewHeight;
```

Update the height constant of the constraint and then update the UIView constraints. The UITableView will change to accommodate the modified UIView.

```
self.uiViewHeight.constant = 150.0f;
[self.uiview1 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

Comment: This solution sounds great...I tried it but can't seem to pin the UIView that is located above the table.  When I try to pin it, the options are greyed out.

Comment: I've put a simple project on github that has a button that alters the UIView height above a UITableView.  Look at the iPhone storyboard for layout.  Hope that helps.   [GitHub](https://github.com/petetodd/uiViewHeightDemo)